# TortoiseSVN checkout failed error svn: E120106: ra_serf: The server sent a truncated HTTP response body

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

TortoiseSVN shows the error `svn: E120106: ra_serf: The server sent a truncated HTTP response body` during checkout operation. How to solve the problem?

Comment: Please add some more detail... for example, which tortoise-version are you using and which version has the subversion server.

Comment: Others may experience the same error but doing a merge. Downgrading the client solved the problem.

Comment: Still a problem in SVN 1.9.3 (windows, commandline)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36180657/761095

Answer (score 13):

Some [ideas](http://svn.haxx.se/tsvn/archive-2014-01/0002.shtml) from TortoiseSVN developer:

> The data sent is too big and the server closes the connection due to 
>   reaching a limit.
>
> Possible steps which can help fix this issue:
>
> - Increase the timeout value on the server
> - set compression level to zero on the server (will make everything  slower but helps with this issue)
> - make sure all proxies that are in between you and the svn server also  have the timeout values increased

[image]

Comment: You will find how to increase the timeout [here](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html).

Comment: Settings for client and Visual SVN server [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20045215/397817).

Answer (score 11):

Then take update instead of again checking out ... Don't delete the Checked out copy, just update it again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Sathish, to be honest, saying that this does not provide an answer to the question is not correct. There is no "question" per se.

Comment: Sathish - AlexChe **does** provide an answer and it works.

Comment: This is a useful answer. You want to checkout a repo, but you're getting an error. Use this workaround and you will be able to complete your checkout.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same issue, but in the context of our CI system teamcity. rather than using teamcity itself to checkout, some scripts do perform manual svn checkout and caused this error.

> Internal SVN clean checkout canceled on large repositories for working
>   copy format 1.7 using the svn.exe via script instead of build-in
>   teamcity SVN with the message: "svn: E120106: ra_serf: The server sent
>   a truncated HTTP response body."

- clean checkout of small repository works regardless of working copy format
- clean checkout of large repository works using working copy format 1.5
- using export instead of checkout works
- using teamcity 8.1.5 internal svn client works (no idea why)
- using svn client 1.7 instead of 1.8 results in a similar timeout related error: "svn: E175002: REPORT of '/!svn/me': Could not read response body: Secure connection truncated"

Increasing the SVN timeout value on the server did indeed fix the problem and neither the "ra_serf" nor the "secure connection truncated error" occurred since.

Aniket Thakur suggestion of reverting the svn client version did have effect on this issue, yet I was unable to find the right version. (if there is one)

Sanmat Jhanjhari suggestion of decreasing the compression level is not only part of the accepted solution but the reason this might work is that it keeps the response time between SVN server and client steady and compressing large files no longer cause timeouts.

changing the working copy to 1.5 is a client side only alternative one could take to resolve this issue. the reason this works is most likely related to the way the data is compressed, but I couldn't figure out the exact reasons.

using export is a dire client side alternative one could take in case you are only interested in the data itself and do not need it to be a repository. export behavior is slightly different though. for example it does not overwrite existing files. I also couldn't figure out why this works compared to normal checkout.

Answer (score 2):

Incorrect Proxy Settings can cause the same error message.

I have encountered the exact same error at different moments during the checkout. The first few files always succeeded, but after 5-10 files the ra_serf error appeared. Same happened with large and small files.

After some trial and error (other hardware, wired connection) I was not closer to a solution. I decided to check all Tortoise SVN settings and found the simple answer: my proxy settings were not correct!

Answer (score 1):

The error **Error: ra_serf: The server sent a truncated HTTP response body** may occur when making a checkout of a huge directory or when the client's disk is very slow. As far as I know, the problem is fixed in the code of Subversion (e.g., see [r1886490](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1886490)). The fix should be included in the next Apache Subversion release. When the fix is released, you need to upgrade your Subversion client to resolve the problem.

The problem has a ticket in the issue tracker of Apache Subversion [SVN-3264](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-3264).

In all other cases when you receive the error **The server sent a truncated HTTP response body** is makes sense to consider the following general troubleshooting steps:

- Make sure to use the latest and most up to date Subversion client version.
- Ensure that an antivirus you may have installed on the client or server computer is not interfering with the Subversion HTTP(S) traffic. You must add exception / exclusion rule that will disable on-access or traffic scan to and from your Subversion server. For example, see the article [KB171: Configuring antivirus exclusions for VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00171/).
- Ensure that a proxy you may have between the client machine and Subversion server is working properly and is not killing the connection prematurely.
- Contact your system administrator to check the network for connection problems.

Answer (score -2):

> SVN 1.8 includes a new HTTP client library (Serf).

which I think is responsible for this. I had installed `TortoiseSVN-1.8.6.25419-x64-svn-1.8.8.msi` and performing `svn merge` gave same error. Initially I though it is problem with svn server timeouts but same merge operation worked with `1.6`. So I guess problem is with SVN version 1.8 and above. **Please revert your svn client version to 1.7 or 1.6 and try!**

Comment: Bug has been raised here, but its seems going back to 1.7 is the only option right now.
https://sourceforge.net/p/tortoisesvn/tickets/678/

Answer (score -2):

Set following key-value in the SVN configuration file. That's it.

```
DeflateCompressionLevel 5
```

1 is the lowest value.
9 is the maximum value.

Comment: "That's it" what? How do you think is it going to solve the problem?