# SVN commit doesn't complete

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

When I commit files in svn I often get the situation where after it has transmitted all the files svn will hang and then eventually time out with the error `svn: E175012: Connection timed out`.

This seems to happen when I am uploading more than say 20 files.

I believe this is happening after all of the files have been transferred to the server as either new periods will have stopped being added after `Transmitting file data` in the console, or all of the files have been listed as sent in Tortoise.  Also, if I then do an update from the repository I get merges for all of the files I've just tried to commit (or, more annoyingly, a ton of conflicts to resolve) and when I then go to commit again there is nothing to commit - presumably meaning all of the files were successfully transmitted the first time.

What could be causing this?  It seems like the client is waiting for a 'all done' message from the server that is never arriving back at my PC?

Our set up is TortoiseSVN 1.8.2 on the client and VisualSVN Server 2.7 on the server.

I've checked for error messages in VisualSVN's event log on the server and there aren't any. This happens on both the office network and over VPN, and whether working on Wi-Fi or a wired connection.

Comment: Is your server resource-constrained? Slow I/O, low on disk space, low on memory, CPU pegged at 100%?

Comment: I have the exact same symptom, but I am only committing one 50 KB file (a pdb file). Other pdb files work fine, just this particular file doesn't. I've recompiled it (different content), tried in different repositories (same server), and it never commits. It transfers the content, then drops to 0 Bps and hangs. SVN or the web server is doing something that is file-based. I asked the admins to look at it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check whether any post-commit hook script is processing your commits.

Comment: 900 is a second? or something else!

Comment: Hi, okay, its seconds. Thanks for updating.

Comment: The key bit of the answer turned out to be "check whether any post-commit hook script is processing your commits".  I found an old BugTracker.net post commit hook on the server.  Once I got rid of that the check in stopped pausing after the last file and hasn't failed to complete a commit since.

(Apologies for the year delay in confirming this)

Comment: The same here; after removing all legacy hooks the commit worked fine for a large fileset.