# Timeout after few commits VisualSVN and TortoiseSVN

Tags: django, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

my problem is as followed:

I am working on a django project atm and am using VisualSVN server (newest version 2.7.4) on my Windows Home Server 2010 for version control. On my Win 8.1 laptop I am programming and commiting files with TortoiseSVN (Version 1.8.5). 
After start, I can commit about 2-3 times and then I get a timeout. I already increased the timeout and keepalive time on the server side, but no change. The Repobrowser is still working. I can make a new checkout without problems. Just commiting is making issues. 
Filesizes are max of 100KB. 
There shouldn't be a timeout then.

Hopefully someone can give me an advise.

Greets,

Christian

Comment: What did you increase the timeout to? Does the failing commit contain a lot of changes? TortoiseSVN should commit only the deltas of the changes, so if the changes are small it should be very short. Take a look [at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20045215/484127), it seems very similar to your issue.

Comment: How much memory does your server have, and how much space available on the drive hosting the temp directory?

Comment: Actually there aren't much changes. Even if it is just 1 file with 3 lines of change. I increased the timeout to 300000 :-)

The server has now 2.8TB space left, the host of the temp directory 250GB.